# How to allow outside folks to search the database

Tags: community

What is the best way to allow potential customers to search (but not edit) the database of inventory (products) by putting in criteria for a custom search? I just want it to return a list. Looks like Chatter (only) and Communities only allow searches on Accounts and Contacts. I can put together a Visualforce Page with the custom search but how to allow access to this or where to put it? Gathering ideas from the community. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and for the link. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve it.

The most easy way(that i can this of) is to [setup public](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) site and add visual force page to it with search capabilities on product.  With help of visual force and standard controller  you should be able to do this very quickly